# How to replace End

Tags: vb6

I am working on a legacy VB6 exe program. There are various situations that the program can no longer continue. Instead of returning the error message to the caller, the program shows the error via message box and then uses `End` to terminate.

Is there any way i can change this behavior with **minimum possible changes**?

For example, I use a global string variable, i will set the error in this global variable wherever `End` is being used instead of showing the error and then by using some keyword/technique i return to the very first caller (instead of the very last caller which happens when i use `Exit Sub/Function`)

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
  Call DoSomething()
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething()
  Call DoThing_1()
  Call DoThing_2()
End Sub

Public Sub DoThing_1()
  Call DoThing_A()
  ...
  Call DoThing_B()
  ...
  MsgBox "Error Here"
  'End  
  Exit Sub 'As i have asked(if possible), instead of returning to DoSomething(), the call should return to Button_Click
  ...
  Call DoThing_C()
  ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give a small sample of, say, three functions calling one another in the current manner, so that the program flow becomes apparent?

Comment: @Tomalak example added

Comment: I cannot see `End` anywhere...?

Comment: @Tomalak `End` is there now but commented, read the comments added after `Exit Sub`

Comment: Hm... You won't be able to return control to the "very first caller", this is not how the call stack works. Control will always return to the next function in the call stack, and if that isn't programmed in a way to expect that the function calls it contains can return in an error state, your program logic will be off when you replace `End` with something else (like `Exit Sub` or `Exit Function`). That means, you need to change each function body that uses `End` *and* add result checks to each function that calls such a function, recursively. There is no easy way around this.

Comment: @Tomalak is there any way to terminate Dll's execution like End does for an exe?

Comment: "DLL execution"? In the sense of "function calls into a COM DLL"?

Comment: @Tomalak I call a function in a dll, now the dll's code is executing, this code faces a fatal error  at 5th level down the hierarchy. Now at this point can i terminate the execution(as it happens in case of `End` for an exe) instead of returning to the callers?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. The library function call is atomic your code, i.e. it's irrelevant how many levels of calls happen inside the DLL. You can neither see what happens in the library, nor can you influence it in any way. You call the library function, this either succeeds or it fails. All you can do catch the error in your code.

Comment: The dll is mine as well, i just need to terminate dll's code execution on error, can i?

Comment: Well, as my answer explains - throwing an error and not handling it will terminate the execution. This works for your DLL in the same way as it would work in your main code. In your main program, the unhandled error from the DLL will be catchable via `On Error`. If your main program throws an unhandled error itself, it will crash.

Comment: @Tomalak As i mentioned it is a legacy application so there are error handlers there as well which will ruin the idea of not handling the error to terminate the program. All i am trying is to minimize the changes required to replace `End`, of course the error message can be returned or un-handled exceptions (or remove existing handlers or add special handlers) but these would require changes in the whole program.

Comment: You won't be able to get away with "minimal" changes, the earlier you get this idea out of your head, the better.

Comment: @Tomalak Ok, thanks

Comment: Not sure what is so hard to believe about that. You cannot change the code's behavior without changing the code.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical way of error management and -recovery in VB is to raise an error and handle ("trap") that error elsewhere higher up in the call stack, using an `On Error` statement.

The raised error will travel up through the call stack until it hits a function that has an error handler defined via `On Error`, or until the call stack is empty, at which point your program will terminate with the error at hand.

So if you replace `End` with `Err.Raise` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/raise-method) on VBA, since MS took great care to obliterate the actual VB language reference), you can do this:

```
Option Explicit

' you don't need to, but it's good style to have meaningful error numbers
' (vbObjectError is the error number after which user-defined errors may exist)
Const MY_ERROR_TYPE_A As Integer = vbObjectError + 1
Const MY_ERROR_TYPE_B As Integer = vbObjectError + 2

Public Sub Button_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_Button_Click

  Call DoSomething

  Exit Sub

Err_Button_Click:
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case MY_ERROR_TYPE_A:
      MsgBox "Error during Button_Click: " & vbNewLine & _
        Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
        "in " & Err.Source, vbExclamation, "Oops"
      Err.Clear
      Resume Next
    Case MY_ERROR_TYPE_B:
      MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "This is really bad."
      End
  End Select
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething()
  Call DoThing_1
  Call DoThing_2
End Sub

Public Sub DoThing_1()
  Dim frob

  Call DoThing_A
  '...
  Call DoThing_B
  '...
  If frob = 0 Then
    Err.Raise MY_ERROR_TYPE_A, "DoThing_1", "Could not frob the buzz"
  End If
  '...
  Call DoThing_C
  '...
End Sub
```

You can see that the brunt of the work is done in the "first caller" function. You still have to identify those throughout your code, though, and add appropriate error handling blocks to them. Chances are you want error handling at least in every event handler.

Here `Button_Click` defines an error handler. Typically this is a block of code only reachable by a certain label, i.e. there is an `Exit Sub`/`Exit Function` in front of it and you need `GoTo` to get there. In that block you can either display a meaningful message to the user and continue the program via `Resume Next`, or end the program, depending on what error you are looking at.

It does not have to be as elaborate as the sample above. You can implement a minimal version of that - no error constants, no messages, just `Err.Raise` and `On Error`, but putting in a bit more effort might turn out as useful in the end, especially in a program that did not have any error handling so far.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I have followed many times here is to change your subs to functions, and have each one return a true/false value indicating whether the program should continue or not. Also, a global Variable to store the error can work, but I prefer an out parameter with the error message.

So, if we use my pattern, your code becomes:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
  Call DoSomething()
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething()
    Dim strErrDescription as String
    If DoThing_1(strErrDescription) Then
        If DoThing_2(strErrDescription) Then
            //Could put a DoThing_3() 'here if desired
        End If
    End if
    'Do something with strErrDescription now
End Sub

'Returns true if we should continue, false if an error happened and we should stop
Public Function DoThing_1(ByRef strErrorDescriptionOut) as Boolean 
  DoThing_1 = True 'Callers continue unless we encounter an error
  Call DoThing_A() 'Note: If you want to follow the same pattern, you can add an if here as well
  ...
  Call DoThing_B() 'Note: If you want to follow the same pattern, you can add an if here as well
  ...
  strErrorDescriptionOut = "Error Here"
  'End  
  DoThing_1 = false
  Exit Function 
  ...
  Call DoThing_C()
  ...
End Function
```

Comment: I'll grant this isn't minimal code changes. To Tomalek's point, I'm not seeing a way to do this with "minimal code changes"